# Return generated HTML from controller and bind it to template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table that can display different content in `td`s depending on some input. For instance, I could have a `button`, `div`, `img`, custom component, etc. Since there is a lot of different data that can be inside the `td`, I created a method that would generate the proper `HTML` and return it. However, I cannot seem to find a way to bind it to my template.

Here is my `HTML` generating method:

```
getComponentForType(type: string): any {
    return this._sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML,`<span> hello world</span>`);
}
```

This method would return more complex `HTML`, but I am just testing with a simple `span` for the moment.

Here is my template:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of data; let rowIndex = index">
            <td *ngFor="let column of columns; let colIndex = index" [attr.safeHtml]="getComponentForType(columns[colIndex].type)">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I tried many things to set the `HTML`. I tried using the `safeHTML`, `innerHTML`, `ng-bind-html` directives and many more, yet my `HTML` never seems to render. This is what Chrome renders this as:

[image: chrome rendering]

How can I manage to add a nested `HTML` element inside the `td` from my method that generates `HTML`?

Comment: You’re now adding it as an attribute so the result looks correct. Did you try [innerHTML]?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your data so I wrote some *dummy* tags as the columns of the HTML elements.

**Edit:**
`return this._sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, type);` will clear styles from the element, remove buttons tags and functionality until the value is safe to use if this is the case just replace `[attr.safeHtml]="getComponentForType(columns[colIndex].type)"` with  `[innerHTML]="getComponentForType(column)"`.

if you do want buttons with click events and\or inline styles then you should use:

`this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(type)` and `[innerHTML]="getComponentForType(column)"`, check out the docs for this topic in https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusthtml.

Warning: If this section in your system will be written to the database by one user and will be rendered to another user then you need to avoid the use of this solution and consider changing your requirements for this part of your system.

From the docs:

> WARNING: calling this method with untrusted user data exposes your
>   application to XSS security risks!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dangerous-table',
    templateUrl: './dangerous-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dangerous-table.component.css']
})
export class DangerousTableComponent implements OnInit {

    data = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'];

    columns = [
        '<span style="color: red;"> Hello XSS </span>',
        '<button onclick="alert(document.domain)">click me</button>',
        '<img src onerror="console.log(JSON.stringify(localStorage))"/>'
    ]

    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    getComponentForType(type: string): any {
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(type);
    }
}
```

and your view:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
            <td
                *ngFor="let column of columns"
                [innerHTML]="getComponentForType(column)"
            >
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try to do it with javascript getElementById

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
```

Once you have done with that, please try to add this

```
function parseHTML(html) {
       var t = document.createElement('template');
       t.innerHTML = html;
       return t.content.cloneNode(true);
   }

   var documentFragment = parseHTML('<td>Test</td>');
```

This would help you to add innerhtml in your project.